# Word for people who don't make their deadline

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

What is the correct word to describe the people who have not finished their work after the deadline?

For the antonym, there is *finisher*, but I can't find **unfinisher* in the dictionary.

Comment: Maybe *non-finisher*?

Comment: Slackers! maybe.

Comment: ...... dead ................................

Comment: Close-voters, what is non-constructive about this question?

Comment: Don't you mean people who have not finished their work _before_ the deadline?  These would be the people who do finish _after_, or who never finish.  Your phrasing seems to be logically similar to a double negative.

Comment: @WarrenT I doubt it... correct me if I'm wrong, I used perfect tense... meaning even after the deadline, they have not finished. If I used before.. I would have said: "people who can't finish their work before the deadline".

Comment: A *dollar-short-and-a-day-later*?

Comment: "Late" is the word I'd use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word I use at work is just "late". They're all late.

Unfinisher doesn't exist, but non-finisher does.

Your question is a little ambiguous though. Are you looking for a word for people who do finish, but after the deadline (flaky), or for people who never complete the work at all (non-finisher)?

Comment: If you go by the questions title, "Word for people who don't make their deadline", then this answer is correct. :)

Comment: So, what do you call a person who is late for a deadline? The question is looking for a noun as its answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Tardy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tardy)

*Occurring, arriving, acting, or done after the scheduled, expected, or usual time; late.*

There's also *under-performing* which doesn't imply anything about deadlines, but describes people who don't meet the expectations.

Answer (score 2):

A person who regularly fails to accomplish what is expected is often called an *[underachiever](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/underachieve?view=uk)*. This is not just limited to lateness but other poor showings.

This author suggests a neologistic phrase *[time optimist](http://thesocialage.com/blog/2008/01/16/why-are-some-people-always-late/)* for someone who chronically believes that they have more time than they do.

Answer (score 2):

The words *finisher* and *deadline* are not related, because *deadline* refers to a date and *finisher* refers to a state. A person is either a *finisher* or they are not.

Perhaps *finisher* vs *procrastinator* would be the best pairing.

John Smith always finishes before the deadline, but Mary Smith finishes after the deadline. They're both finishers; *deadline* is just a reference to a date. You have to apply logical rules for it to make any sense.

The opposite of *finish* is *start*, but there is no opposite for *finisher*. You could say Mary Smith is a *starter* but that has a completely different meaning than the opposite of *finisher*.

One could say the opposite of *finisher* is *quitter*. Since someone who never finishes must have quit.

Furthermore, the question in a way is in error, since a *finisher* could also be someone who always finishes after the deadline, but at least they always finish.

Answer (score 1):

In scheduling theory, The standard terminology for how soon an action’s completion occurs before its deadline is called “earliness.” How far an action’s completion occurs after its deadline is called “tardiness.” Earliness and tardiness are formally defined in terms of “lateness,” as follows: 
lateness = completion time - deadline;
earliness = max [0, -lateness];
tardiness = max [0, lateness].

Answer (score 0):

*Procrastinator* is someone who keeps delaying things.

Comment: but that is completely unrelated to missing deadlines or not.

Comment: unrelated to deadlines, is true, but so is finisher. I think this answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I simply call them 'procrastinators'. Though, the term itself doesn't imply missing deadlines. 'Behind' can imply finishing late, but can also be used to determine their progress within the scope of a project that will be completed on time.

A few synonyms I've found that may work depending on the content...

- Belated
- Unpunctual
- Delayed
- Tardy
- Delinquent
- Overdue
- Dilatory
- Remiss
- Lackadaisical

src: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/belated and simply clicking around within.